# How to make setuptools follow symlinks?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to set up a python package for distribution. I haven't done this before, so I'm pretty hazy about best practices, or even how to make things work, and I've run into a problem. My project structure looks like this:

```
ROIWidgets/
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
    setup.cfg
    ROIWidgets/
        __init__.py
    static/
        widgets/
            js -> <symlink to folder containing JavaScript files>
```

The problem is with the JS files under static. I started with `distutils`. I included this line in `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include static *
```

...and that caused the JS to be included in the package. Nice. Then I read that if I want my setup script to automatically install dependencies, I need to use `setuptools` rather than `distutils`. So, I switched: I import `setup` from `setuptools` rather than `distutils`. But now, when I say `setup.py sdist`, this line appears in the output:

```
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'static'
```

...and the JS files are not included in the distribution. After a long session with the debugger, I located the problem in `setuptools/__init__.py`. Here it is:

```
def findall(dir = os.curdir):
    """Find all files under 'dir' and return the list of full filenames
    (relative to 'dir').
    """
    all_files = []
    for base, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        if base==os.curdir or base.startswith(os.curdir+os.sep):
            base = base[2:]
        if base:
            files = [os.path.join(base, f) for f in files]
        all_files.extend(filter(os.path.isfile, files))
    return all_files

distutils.filelist.findall = findall    # fix findall bug in distutils.
```

`os.walk` does not by default follow symlinks. So the `setuptools` version of `findall` isn't looking in my `js` directory. `distutils` `findall` didn't use `os.walk` -- instead it had its own directory walking code. From the changelog, it appears that `distutils` `findall` had a problem with broken symlinks, which this replacement was intended to address. It would have been easy enough to use `os.walk(dir, followlinks=True)`, but perhaps there was some reason why that was a bad idea?

So I'm kind of stuck. Either I change the structure of my project, which I'm loathe to do, or I muck with `distutils` and `setuptools` internals, a prospect that makes me even less happy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was apparently fixed in the repository at the time of your question (possibly too early for the fix to have become widespread).

I believe this means the relevant version tag for a fixed setuptools package is `8.0.2`. Updating to that version solves the issue.